Borel Sigma algebra generated by given set
Fix any $ r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Let
$$ \mathcal{D}=\bigg\{m+\dfrac{r}{2^n}:m\in\mathbb{Z},\,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\bigg\}\text{ and }   
 \mathcal{I}_\mathcal{D}=\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathcal{D},\,a<b\}. $$
Then $ \sigma$-algebra  generated by $\mathcal{I}_\mathcal{D}$ and  $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ are not equal.
In my reference text it is given  that $ \sigma$-algebra generated by open intervals with rational end points and $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$(Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R})$  are the same. By learning that proof I got to know that in the above set $\mathcal{D}$ , if they have given the restriction like $m\in\mathbb{Z},\,n\in\mathbb{Z}.$ $\hspace{1mm}$
Then $ \sigma$-algebra  generated by $\mathcal{I}_\mathcal{D}$ and   $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ are equal. Am I correct here?

You can assume without loss of generality that $r \in (0,1) \setminus \Bbb Q$.
Take $s$ such that $r <s <1$. Let $\sigma(\mathcal{I}\mathcal{D})$ be the $\sigma$-algebra  generated by $\mathcal{I}\mathcal{D}$.
Prove that, for all $(a,b) \in \mathcal{I}_\mathcal{D}$, $(s,1] \subseteq (a,b)$ or $(s, 1] \cap (a,b)=\emptyset$. Prove that $\mathcal{A} = { E \subseteq \Bbb R: (s,1] \subseteq E \text{ or } (s, 1] \cap E=\emptyset }$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. (continue)

Since $\mathcal{I}\mathcal{D} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, we have that $\sigma(\mathcal{I}\mathcal{D}) \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. So, for all $E \in \sigma(\mathcal{I}\mathcal{D})$, $(s,1] \subseteq E$ or $(s, 1] \cap E=\emptyset$. So the set ${\frac{s+1}{2}}$ is in $\mathcal{B}\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\sigma(\mathcal{I}_\mathcal{D})$.

Thank you so much
